# Conditional counting: Performance differences in using SUM() vs COUNT()?

Tags: sql, count, query-optimization

Just as a very simple example, let's say I have table `test` with sample data like so:

```
a     |     b      
-------------
1     |    18
1     |    24
1     |    64
1     |    82
1     |    10
1     |     7
2     |     5
2     |    18
2     |    66
2     |    72
3     |    81
3     |    97
```

And for each `a`, I'm to get the count of how many `b`'s there are that are < 50. The result would look like:

```
a     |   bcnt
--------------
1     |      4
2     |      2
3     |      0
```

Now I could achieve this result in either of two ways:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(CASE WHEN b < 50 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS bcnt
FROM test
GROUP BY a
```

Or:

```
SELECT a, SUM(CASE WHEN b < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bcnt
FROM test
GROUP BY a
```

I know this may seem like such an insignificant trivial matter, but my question is would there be any advantage (however so slight) in using one approach over the other in terms of: Performance?... How many other DBMSs they would work in?... Clarity of statement?... etc.

Comment: "I want to get the **count** of..." To ask is to answer? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Performance?

Oh, the difference, if any, would be marginal, I'm sure. It would be nothing for me to worry about.

> How many other DBMSs they would work in?

I've no doubt both would work in any *major* SQL product at least, so, again, this wouldn't be a matter of concern, not to me anyway.

> Clarity of statement?

Certainly `COUNT` expresses it clearer that you want to *count* things, not to *add up* some arbitrary values. With `SUM`, you would realise the actual intention only upon reaching the `THEN 1` part after skimming through the condition.

Also, if I use `COUNT` I can omit the `ELSE NULL` part, because that's what is implied when `ELSE` is absent. If I omit `ELSE 0` in the `SUM` expression, I may end up with a `NULL` result instead of the probably expected `0`.

On the other hand, there *may* be quite opposite situations where it would be more convenient to return `NULL` instead of `0` as a result of counting. So, if I used `COUNT`, I would have to do something like `NULLIF(COUNT(CASE ...), 0)`, while with `SUM(CASE ...)` it would be just enough to leave out the `ELSE` clause. But even in that case I might still prefer the somewhat longer clarity to the slightly more obscure brevity (other things being equal).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use

```
select a, count(b)
  from test
 where b < 50
 group by a
```

Clear, concise and according to this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3004f/5) a tiny bit quicker than the others (needs less data according to the execution plan, though with a table that small you won't notice a difference):

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with a where clause:

```
select a, count(b)
from test
where b < 50
group by a
```

Comment: Eh? Having is for filter results of aggregate functions. Do you mean where?

Answer (score -1):

With COUNT, you count the elements, using SUM you add numbers (positive, negative or zero) for a result that can be negative.