# SQL - counting rows with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
id  value
1   0
1   1
1   2
1   0
1   1
2   2
2   1
2   1
2   0
3   0
3   2
3   0
```

Now for each `id`, I want to count the number of occurences of 0 and 1 and the number of occurences for that ID (the value can be any integer), so the end result should look something like this:

```
id  n0  n1  total
1   2   2   5
2   1   2   4
3   2   0   3
```

I managed to get the first and last row with this statement:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY id;
```

But I'm sort of lost from here. Any pointers on how to achieve this without a huge statement?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With MySQL, you can use `SUM(condition)`:

```
SELECT   id, SUM(value=0) AS n0, SUM(value=1) AS n1, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2a5c/1/0).

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know even know there was a `SUM(condition)`!

Comment: @ryyst: Well, it's a trick that takes advantage of the fact that MySQL evaluates the boolean results of conditional expressions to 0 if false and 1 if true; so taking the `SUM` over each group provides a count of those records where the condition is true.

Comment: You could also be more expressive and use `COUNT(CASE WHEN value=0 THEN 1 END) AS n0, ..., ...`, which will work in all other major DBMSs as MySQL is the only one to make implicit boolean conversions. See my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340540/conditional-counting-performance-differences-in-using-sum-vs-count) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zane commented above, the typical method is to use CASE expressions to perform the pivot.

SQL Server now has a PIVOT operator that you might see. DECODE() and IIF() were older approaches on Oracle and Access that you might still find lying around.