# MySQL sum() with condition in jOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

MySQL will allow me to pass a condition as a parameter to SUM().

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(value > 100) FROM TABLE1;
```

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11377479/3419).

How do I do this in JOOQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (as of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) 3.4), the [`DSL.sum()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.4.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#sum-org.jooq.Field-) function takes a `Field<? extends Number>` argument, so what you want to do needs some tweaking on types. Here are two alternative ways to implement that query:

```
// Static imports are assumed to be present:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

DSLContext ctx = using(configuration);

// Solution 1) Coerce Field<Boolean> to Field<Number>
ctx.select(count(), sum(field(TABLE1.VALUE.gt(100)).coerce(Integer.class)))
   .from(TABLE1)
   .fetch();

// Solution 2) Resort to a raw type cast
ctx.select(count(), sum((Field) field(TABLE1.VALUE.gt(100))))
   .from(TABLE1)
   .fetch();
```

In both solutions, you will need to transform an [`org.jooq.Condition`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html) into an [`org.jooq.Field`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html) by calling [`DSL.field(Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-). This has no effect on the generated SQL when using MySQL which natively supports this kind of usage for boolean types. If you were using a database without support for boolean types, `DSL.field(Condition)` would generate a `CASE` expression.

In jOOQ 4.0 ([Issue #3415](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3415)), the `DSL.sum()` function is scheduled to relax argument type constraints so that the call to `coerce()` or the cast to `(Field)` are no longer needed.

Comment: When I do Solution 1, I get an exception "org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.lang.Number is not supported in dialect null." I am using version 3.4.1.

Comment: Yep, you're right of course. I changed the class to `Integer.class`