# How count 10 different IP's in mySQL table

Tags: mysql, count

I'm relatively new to mySQL.  I'm trying to count all occurences of each ip in my table, but I'm not sure how to get the query to group them all separately with counts for me.  This is what I have so far and an example of my table.

```
TableData:
MAC                 IP       Status
AAAA.AAAA.AAAA  xx.xxx.xx.78   6
AAAA.AAAA.AACA  xx.xxx.xx.131  1
AAAA.AAAA.AABA  xx.xxx.xx.31   5
AAAA.AAAA.AAAD  xx.xxx.xx.31   NULL
AAAA.AAAA.AAAC  xx.xxx.xx.78   1
AAAA.AAAA.AAAB  xx.xxx.xx.131  6
AAAA.AAAA.AAAF  xx.xxx.xx.31   6
AAAA.AAAA.AABB  xx.xxx.xx.131  5
AAAA.AAAA.AABB  xx.xxx.xx.131  6

SELECT COUNT(IP='xx.xxx.xx.31') COUNT(IP='xx.xxx.xx.131'), COUNT(IP='xx.xxx.xx.78') TABLEDATA WHERE Status IS NOT NULL

Result wanted:
xx.xxx.xx.31   2
xx.xxx.xx.78   2
xx.xxx.xx.131  4
```

I was looking at [count rows specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377446/sql-counting-rows-with-specific-value) but this seems different and I'm having trouble applying this principle, if that's what I need.  I'm having a tough time thinking of what to search on the internet for this.

Updated - Showing a duplicate MAC for a given IP in results and table data.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: You want to `GROUP BY` IP and `COUNT` the result

Comment: I tried Select COUNT(IP) FROM TableData WHERE Status IS NOT NULL GROUP BY IP and it shows me a list of counts without the ip's next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a GROUP BY

```
SELECT
    MAC,
    IP,
    COUNT(IP)
FROM
    TABLEDATA
WHERE
    Status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    MAC,
    IP
```

Comment: It's interesting.  That's showing me the same result as SELECT DISTINCT IP, COUNT(IP) FROM TABLEDATA WHERE Status IS NOT NULL GROUP BY IP.  Does your query drop duplicates?

Comment: @Michele You don't get duplicates when you use GROUP BY, because the only columns you have are IP and COUNT(IP) so MySQL shows you each unique IP and how many times that appears (by counting them). The DISTINCT isn't needed and probably makes MySQL do work that's unnecessary.

Comment: Hmmm...I wanted it to include the duplicates.

Comment: Can you update the "Results Wanted" part of your question to show me what you need please?

Comment: Ok, I added a duplicate mac for a given ip and the resulting output.

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted MAC in the results. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't need MAC in the answer.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I just don't want it to drop the duplicate IP's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170786/discussion-between-flip-and-michele).

Answer (score 1):

I think this would have to work for you. This will show the result you wanted almost exactly, the IP will show just the last digits, not like this xx.xxx.xx.10. You can edit that if you want. The cast as unsigned function in the order row is to order the last digits as integers.

```
SELECT substring_index(ip, '.', -1), count(ip) 
FROM TableData
WHERE Status is not null 
GROUP BY substring_index(ip, '.', -1), status 
ORDER BY cast(substring_index(ip, '.', -1) as UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: I don't need to just see the last 4 digits of the ip.  I just didn't want to post ip's here.

Comment: Oooo yes, now that I read it again I see that I understood it wrong. Well, it was a good practice anyway hehe.

Comment: Thanks though!  :)