# Can I get two counts from mysql with a conditional where statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently getting a users visit count based on a timestamp but I would also like to include the total number of visits.  Is this possible to do with one MySQL statement.  Here is my current query that returns only one count based on a timestamp:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as visitors_count FROM profile_visits
        LEFT JOIN users on users.user_id=profile_visits.user_id
        LEFT JOIN profile_info ON profile_info.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE profile_user_id=5
        AND users.restricted <> 1
        AND profile_visits.visit_time > '2012-07-30 18:53:16'";
```

Can I also return the total number of visits that exclude the timestamp?

Comment: what do you mean by `I would also like to include the total number of visits.`?

Comment: I want to exclude the timestamp restriction for a total count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression to conditionally aggregate within `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN profile_visits.visit_time > '2012-07-30 18:53:16' THEN 1 END) AS visitors_count
FROM      profile_visits
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=profile_visits.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_info ON profile_info.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE     profile_user_id=5 AND 
          users.restricted <> 1
```

I simply moved the `> '2012-07-30 18:53:16'` from the `WHERE` clause to the `CASE` expression within `COUNT()` which will only count the row if it meets that criteria. And of course `COUNT(*)` will count all rows regardless of the timestamp.

Comment: That worked...I've never used or heard of CASE expressions. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to use SUM instead of COUNT! And a simple IF statement is much prettier.

Comment: @MehranZiadloo, could you explain your reasoning for that? Using `COUNT()` makes it clear to the reader that you're ***counting*** rows. We are not summing anything. Moreover, the `CASE`-expression is DBMS-agnostic meaning that it will work in all major DBMSs including SQLServer, Oracle, PGSQL, etc. etc. `IF()` is only MySQL-specific. So using `COUNT()` has an advantage in clarity of statement, and `CASE` has an advantage in DBMS-abstraction. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340540/conditional-counting-performance-differences-in-using-sum-vs-count) for more info.

Comment: Are there any performance advantages between CASE and the answer @Angelo provided below (which also works well)

Comment: @Paul, my solution queries the table only once whereas the other answer is executing ***three*** different `SELECT` statements, not to mention that it's generally bad practice to put subqueries right into the `SELECT` clause. Moreover, the other answer's "complete_count" counts all rows regardless of user_id and restricted (which is seemingly what you still want to filter on for the total count).